# how can i aggregate in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections points collection    and users collection here i want to do aggregation based on userid

```
  points collection           
{
    "userpoint": "2",
    "purchaseid":"dj04944",
    "store":"001",
    "date":ISODate("2017-11-10T08:15:39.736Z")
    "userid"[
    objectID("5a7565ug8945rt67"),
    objectID("8a35553d3446rt78")
    ]
},
{
    "userpoint": "4",
    "purchaseid":"5678sd",
     "store":"004",
    "date":ISODate("2017-11-11T08:15:39.736Z")
    "userid"[
     objectID("9a85653d3890rt09")
    ]
}

users collection

{
   objectID("5a7565ug8945rt67"),
   "name":"asdf",
   "mobinumber":"12345",

},
{
   objectID("8a35553d3446rt78"),
   "name":"qwr",
   "mobinumber":"11111",

},
```

{
       objectID("9a85653d3890rt09"),
       "name":"juir",
       "mobinumber":"9611",

```
}
```

how can i do aggregation

```
db.points.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "users",
          localField: "",
          foreignField: "",
          as: "inventory_docs"
        }
   }
])
```

i want to combine both collections
help me out to move forward

Comment: You need to describe what you want to do in words.  What's the result that you need?   Do you need some fields from users collection in the aggregation?

Comment: i need to combine two collection yeah i need all the fields from users collection @AsyaKamsky

Comment: So just use localField "userid" and foreignField "_id"

Comment: You didn't specify what the name of the field in users is that has the ObjectId, but I'm assuming it's "_id" field.

Comment: Please stop spamming comments on unrelated questions asking people to answer this. These comments have all been deleted.

Comment: "userid"[
    objectID("5a7565ug8945rt67"),
    objectID("8a35553d3446rt78")
    ] these two ids presented in users collection document ids (_id)@Asya Kamsky

Comment: If I use like this  localField "userid" and foreignField "_id" it's not working showing 0 document

Comment: what is your expected result? could you pls add expected result in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your expected output like bellow

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a164fa5400096bfa0b3422c"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-11-10T08:15:39.736Z"),
    "name" : "asdf",
    "mobile" : "12345"
}
```

The can try this query

```
db.points.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
      store: "001",
      date: {$lte: ISODate("2017-11-10T08:15:39.736Z"), $gte: ISODate("2017-11-10T08:15:39.736Z")}
    }
  },
  {$unwind: "$userid"},
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "userid",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "user"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      userpoint: 1,
      purchaseid: 1,
      date: 1,
      user: {$arrayElemAt: ["$user", 0]}
    }
  },
  {$match: {"user.name": "asdf"}},
  {
    $project: {
      date: 1,
      name: "$user.name",
      mobile: "$user.mobinumber"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: i should get only   "store":"001", ISODate("2017-11-10T08:15:39.736Z") and "name":"asdf"

Comment: In your `store: 001` has 2 user so why you want to get only name `asdf`? what is your actual condition you should describe clearly in your question that what your criteria, what you want etc.... @itsme

Comment: store: 001 has two user(it may be multiple user) but sometime i want to know only that particular user(find by name)

Comment: also want to find by store ?

Comment: want to find by store,  between two dates , name

Comment: you need add fields in `$project` stage that you need @itsme